# ADODB - how to get only the total number of records

Tags: sql, adodb

What is the best way to get JUST the total number of records?

Comment: Probably 'best' to do the count at source e.g. `select count(*) from mytable` etc then read the value from the recordset's field.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim oRS as new ADODB.Recordset
dim recordCount as Long

oRS.Open "Select * FROM [tablename]", myConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
If Not oRS.EOF Then recordCount = oRS.RecordCount
```

The key here is `adOpenStatic`.  It allows .RecordCount to get an actual count of the records in the recordset.

Of course, if all you're after is how many records in a table:

```
Dim oRS as new ADODB.Recordset
dim recordCount as Long

oRS.Open "Select Count(*) FROM [tablename]", myConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
If Not oRS.EOF Then recordCount = oRS(0).Value
```

Comment: I think you are slightly confused about `CursorType` values. The `RecordCount` property should also have a meaningful value (rather than `-1`) when using `adOpenStatic`. `adOpenDynamic` is required for synchronous (immediate) updates to the data source, unlikely to be a requirement when the spec says, "JUST the total number of records" (plus you are using a read only lock!) Not all OLE DB providers support it anyhow e.g. MS Access doesn't. For your first example `adOpenStatic` is adequate. For your second example, you could use the even 'cheaper' `adOpenForwardOnly`.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Thanks.  Actually I wasn't confused.  It's just harder to remember/type this stuff without the benefit of intellisense ;)

Answer (score 0):

ADOQuery, SQL= "select count(*) from mytable where xyz"?

rs.RecordCount?

```
i = 0
while not rs.eof
  i = i + 1
  rs.next?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these solutions.

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename>

With rs
  .CursorType = 3
  .CursorLocation = 3
  .Open sql, RecEngine  
  MsgBox .RecordCount & " records"
End With
```

Assuming an already open Connection (Done in QTP/UFT):

```
Set RecEngine = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
RecEngine.Open <connectionString>
set rs = RecEngine.Execute("SELECT count(*) FROM <tablename>")
MsgBox rs(0)
```

Or using same open connection:

```
If rs.Supports(adApproxPosition) = TRUE Then
  i = rs.RecordCount
  MsgBox i  
  'MsgBox rs.Fields(0).Value & " records"  'If doing select * rather than select count(*)   
End If
```